# POSTGRES PROCEDURE with wildcard

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-12

I am trying to create a procedure with a wildcard with postgresql unfortunately I do not have any success. It looks like the postgresql versions have different ways of creating procedures, however, I find more help on SQL Server. Here the simple procedure I am trying to create:

```
create procedure getpeople (title varchar, city varchar)
LANGUAGE plpgsql 
as $$
select * from salesperson where job_title=title and city like % city

$$;
```

I am using postgreSQL12.1not

Comment: What do you want this procedure to do?  Procedures do not return data, so I would guess you actually want a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the answer by @Emilio Platzer: If you want to get multiple lines out of your function (not procedure) using `PL/pgSQL`, you can set it to return a table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getpeople (varchar,varchar) 
RETURNS TABLE (name text, job_title text, city text)
AS $$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY 
 (SELECT * FROM salesperson sp
  WHERE sp.job_title=$1 AND sp.city LIKE $2||'%');
END  
$$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

.. and call it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM getpeople('ceo','D');
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f5f412a029ce186fea269953915b3c1e)

Comment: thanks, this is exactly I am looking for. But can you tell me how you are mapping the columns please? what are $1, $2?what would $0 represent?

Comment: @Herc01 $1 and $2 corresponds to the `varchar` parameters used to call the function `getpeople (varchar,varchar)`. $0 does not exist :)

Answer (score 1):

You must write the result type. And the language is `sql` not `plpgsql`.

This works:

```sql
create table salesperson(
    name text,
    job_title text,
    city text
);

create function getpeople (title varchar, city varchar) 
  returns salesperson
LANGUAGE sql 
as $$
select * from salesperson where job_title=title and city like '%'||city
$$;

insert into salesperson values ('Boby', 'bos', 'ny');

select getpeople('bos','ny');
```